# How to send text to Linkedin password field

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the Linkedin login page. But the I can not pass text in to its password filed. I check the password filed visibility by using webElement.isDsiplyed() and password field is disable. Password text field contain in a form. Thats mean It's not using javascript. I tried below methods.

01.

```
WebElement linkedinPassword =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='password-input']//div/input"));
    linkedinPassword.click();
    linkedinPassword.sendKeys(new String[] { vars.get("LinkedinPassword") });
```

2. Method 01 with wait time.

Error in the logs;

```
[org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'achini-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-5th', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.verifyCanInteractWithElement(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:283)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.sendKeys(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:327)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80)
    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858)
    at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
    at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130)
    at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80)
    at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:46)
    at bsh.BSHTryStatement.eval(BSHTryStatement.java:86)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:78)
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:222)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:498)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)][1]
```

Anybody have idea how to do the login in to Linkedin using selenium.

Comment: You may want to be cautious doing so: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/6cjtlo/got_banned_from_linkedin_for_using_selenium_how/

Comment: Try `var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 9999);`

Comment: You should share block of HTML Code,

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled to know why you are trying to click in Password input box.My code suggestion would be (make things simple):

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlywait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElementByXpath("//li[@class='password-input']//div/input")).sendkeys("yourpassword");

If still its unable to identify then kindly, check the Xpath you have used and whether you are able to fetch from the DOM.

Comment: I have experienced some text field will allow you to write after given click on it or after send a key release.This is a commonly use method in selenium to avoid failures.

Comment: Ohh is that!! I have never experienced this scenario if suppose send keys() method is not working you could use the below one:                                    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

   
 executor.executeScript("document.getElementById("textbox_id").value='new value');

Answer (score 0):

To identify the **Password** field you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.login-password#login-password").send_keys("Achini")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='login-password' and @id='login-password']").send_keys("Achini")
  ```

**Note**: In this solution I am expecting that you have already induced *WebDriverWait* for the *`Email or phone number`* to be clickable. So I have dropped *WebDriverWait* for **Password** field.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the support. 
 problem solve after I disable the java scripts support since I used selenium with HTMUnit driver. This issue will occurs in automating bootstrap web pages .

To disable the JS support

```
public HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME, false);
```

and to enable it again

```
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Reference: https://newfivefour.com/java-selenium-bootstrap-htmlunit.html